# this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key Image1

Tags: ios, xcode

При запуске возникает ошибка: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key...

Проект пишу с нуля. Ошибка появилась, когда скопировал и попробовал сбилдить код из аналогичного проекта, потом код убрал, ошибка осталась. Image1 - это вью на форме.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Можно это починить или сториборд делать заново?

Проект:  https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B747MENi-kV0RUJMa1M2clBjbms/view?usp=sharing

Comment: дай описание ошибки и пару скришотов сторибоарда. Не буду ж я твой проект дебажить ,)

Comment: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Жаль что просьбу про скриншот ты проигнорировал. Попробую, значит, угадать. У класса, который реализован в коде, нет того аутлета, который ты ставишь в сторибоарде. Видимо, ты не полностью перенес класс из другого проекта или что-то в нем удалил.

Поищи название класса и ключа в логе (оно там есть), найди это в сторибоарде и удали связь. Она должна подсвечиваться желтым цветом.

Comment: как я проигнорировал, скриншот в вопросе

Comment: странно, у меня он появился только сейчас. Тогда пардон. Вызови контекстное меню для верхних обьектов и удали желтые связи. Также нажми на красную стрелочку (справа от View Controller Scene) и исправь ошибки из списка

Comment: Это помогло. В контекстном меню стало заметно,  что есть неактивные аутлеты. Просто снес их и приложение запустилось. большое спасибо.